# Why "file exists" trying to add folder to DFS namespace?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I've got a working (via normal share) shared folder on a server.  However, when I try to add it to our DFS namespace it fails with "The file exists" error.  I'm looking at the namespace and it clearly does NOT exist.  At least not now, but it *may* have in the past.  Is there a cache that needs to be cleared?  I'm using the same procedure that's always worked before, but am getting different results, so obviously something out of the ordinary is going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read on-line, sometimes DFS can cache obsolete data for awhile.  Finally after roughly 36 hours from the initial try (with me re-trying periodically every couple of hours), it just magically worked...